# Stuck on Redux Project

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I was on this exercise trying to implement a simple game.
I am new to redux and having a hard time to understand how payload and state are linked together and got stuck on this exercise.

I still have a doubt whether I should update the state accessing the payload property or if I have to return it directly in the switch statement.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
const initialWagonState = {
  supplies: 100,
  distance: 0,
  days: 0
}

const gather = {
  type:'gather',
  payload: {
  }
}
const travel = {
  type:'travel',
  payload:{
  }
}

const tippedWagon = {
  type:'tippedWagon',
  payload:{
  }
}
  

const reducer = (state=initialWagonState,action=gather) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'gather':{
      return {
      ...state,supplies:state.supplies + 15,
      ...state,distance: state.distance,
      ...state,days: state.days + 1
      }
    }
    case 'travel':{
      return {
    ...state,supplies: state.supplies - (20 * daysOfTravel),
      ...state,distance: state.distance + (10 * daysOfTravel),
      ...state,days: state.days + daysOfTravel
      }
    }
    case 'tippedWagon':{
      return {
      ...state,supplies:state.supplies - 30,
      ...state,distance:state.distance,
      ...state,days: state.days + 1
      }
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

let wagon = reducer('travel');
console.log(wagon)
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not using redux toolkit? https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start this guide will answer your question but using the reduxtookit instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we dispatch an action like dispatch(gather) or dispatch({type: 'gather', payload: any value}). The store runs the reducer function with the previous state and the current action and saves the return value as the new state.

Example:

```
const initialWagonState = {
  supplies: 100,
  distance: 0,
  days: 0
}

const reducer = (state=initialWagonState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'gather':{
      return {
      ...state, supplies: state.supplies + action.payload, days: state.days + 1
      }
    }
}

dispatch({type:'gather',payload: 15})
```

Here, the reducer function receives initialWagonState as state because we dispatch the action for the first time and the reducer function receives {type:'gather', payload: 15} as action. The newly updated state will be the object that returns by the reducer function. So after the first update, the state will be updated like

```
   {
      supplies: 115,
      distance: 0,
      days: 1
    }
```

let's dispatch another action and see what happens

```
dispatch({type:'gather',payload: 20})
```

This time our reducer function receives {supplies: 115, distance: 0, days: 1} as state and {type:'gather',payload: 20} as payload. So after the second update, the state will be updated like

```
       {
          supplies: 135,
          distance: 0,
          days: 2
        }
```

Hope it helps

[Concepts and Data Flow of Redux](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-2-concepts-data-flow)

[Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns)

Answer (score 0):

In redux you cannot directly change the state you must use pure functions or shallow copy of the state and then return a new state. Instead, try to use redux-toolkit because it allows us to directly change the state. Hope this helps!